# Stop ingesting AppDependencies data into Log Analytics Workspace

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, kql

I have an application that ingests lot of data into Log Analytics Workspace in Azure. I tried to run below Kusto query to figure out which piece is generating and ingesting more data in Log Analytics Workspace. And I found that **AppDependencies** was generating and ingesting major chunk of data. And I am looking for any suggestions/solutions on how to stop ingesting only the **AppDependencies** data in Log Analytics Workspace ?

```
union withsource = tt *
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)
| where _IsBillable == true
| summarize BillableDataMBytes = sum(_BilledSize)/ (1000. * 1000.) by tt
| render piechart
```

Answer (score 4):

You can stop dependency tracking by setting `EnableDependencyTrackingTelemetryModule` to `false` in your application insights configuration.

For example, here's what application insights configuration looks like for one of our projects where we have turned off dependency tracking:

```
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "None"
    },
    "EnableAdaptiveSampling": false,
    "EnableDependencyTrackingTelemetryModule": false,
    "ConnectionString": "application-insights-connection-string"
  }
```

You may also find this link useful for fine tuning the data collected by application insights: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core

Comment: Might be worth mentioning filtering or sampling the telemetry data which can also drastically reduce the data ingest into log analytics. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Gaurav! But mine is not a .NET application, it's a Java application so I believe I should find this kind of setting in Pom.xml file. But any idea which configuration in Pom.xml should be updated ? I do not see "EnableDependencyTrackingTelemetryModule" in my Pom.xml file

Comment: Not really sure about Java. Have you seen this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-get-started?tabs=maven?

Comment: Also, please see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-in-process-agent. HTH.

Comment: Yes, I looked at that one earlier. But, couldn't figure out. I'll try more and update in case I am able to figure this out. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: It would certainly help if you can edit your question and include details about your application like what version of SDK you're using, how you have configured the application insights and what external dependencies you're using in your application.